# Can python check if the first variable is true or false with other statements ? see to understand

Tags: python, logical-operators

I want to know if in "if complex statements" can you check if the first element is true or false, then see if either the second or third element is true or false, and if the first element is True And either the second or third element is true, then the "if statement" is true and maybe print something (working), otherwise all the conditions would be false, and simply the "if statement" wouldn't work.

What i wrote :

```
money = 100
hungry = True
bored =  True
if money >= 80 and hungry == True or bored == True :
     print ("You can buy something!")
```

The problem is Whether the (>=) was like that or (<=) the same result would happen, which is the print, unless i make the two variables (hungry and bored) = false, the print wouldn't work.
please tell me what is wrong with this, is it the way "And" and "or" work doesn't support the way i wanted it to work, or what ?

Comment: Also note that `a == True` can be simplified to just `a`. The full expression you want is `money >= 80 and (hungry or bored)`.

Comment: wow, this is my first experience using Stackoverflow, and it was cool because of you! thanks! I'm new to programming and Python is my first language, and i'm learning online, right now i'm following this one https://youtu.be/mDKM-JtUhhc?si=_el1o16C_2S80wRP     in the time 3:56:00 he asked for an exercise, and he solve it just like how i wrote it (you can check that if you want) and he was claiming that this is the write solution, but after i checked different cases this what happens. the video was before 1 year so maybe Py changed ? or the instru was wrong ? note: he didn't show diffe cases

Comment: The operator precedence rules haven't changed since the 90s, so the person creating the video was just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just add parenthesis in the or part of the condition:

```py
if money >= 80 and (hungry == True or bored == True):
     print ("You can buy something!")
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".